# Efficiency of execution time tracking in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators, execution-time

I'm working on a time-critical application in Python. To identify locations and situations, where a most of time is consumed, I wrote a tracking decorator, similar to this one:

```
tracker_repository = {}
def track(name: str = "default", active: bool = None) -> Callable:
    if name not in tracker_repository:
        tracker_repository[name] = []
    def track_f(f) -> Callable:
        if not active: 
            return f
        def exec_f(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            start_time = time.time()
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            end_time = time.time()
            tracker_repository[name].append({
                "f": f,
                "args": args,
                "kwargs": kwargs,
                "start_time": start_time, 
                "end_time": end_time
            })
            return result
        return exec_f
    return track_f
```

And I use it like this:

```
@track()
def some_function(input):
    return "output"
```

Unfortunately, it turns out that using this tracking decorator in every function of the code base slows down execution speed considerably, it is about 3 times slower than before. This holds true even if the decorator is "deactivated". If the "active" flag is False, then the original function is returned, `exec_f` is thus not even touched.

Do you have an idea what could be the issue here and how the tracking code can be improved to have a less big impact on the timing? Or are there better alternatives to measure execution time of the program parts in real-life?

Comment: Why don't you use profiler? https://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/1099716

Comment: Why not use one of the many existing tools for benchmarking and profiling?

Comment: I didn't knew `cProfiler` yet. Thanks for the mention. However, the reason I implemented this in the first place was that I didn't wanted to profile the whole application, only a specific part of it. I used the profiler of PyCharm and it shows me everything, including the startup code. Although that code makes up the largest part of the runtime, but I'm not interested in it. I just want to track the execution times of the functions that are called repeatedly, not only those at the startup of the application. But those are not found in the result or make up only a tiny portion of the runtime.